# What's this little reddish beetle?

Tags: identification, pests

They are plentiful right now, which tends to make me suspicious. I'm noticing them around the Brussels sprouts and zucchini, but they may be congregating elsewhere too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the [striped cucumber beetle](https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef311) who is there for the zucchini.  However as J B S Haldane [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._B._S._Haldane#Quotations) "The creator, if he exists, has an inordinate fondness for beetles".  With over 400,000 species it may be a look a like.  These guys cause a bacterial wilt and row covers are the best organic control.  Site cleanup in the fall helps reduce the spring population

[image: cucumber beetle]

University of Kentucky Entomology